# Which is the corresponding Spring Framework of .NET?

Tags: .net

Spring is used to develop MVC web application in Java... What is the equivalent framework used in .NET Framework to develop MVC application?

Answer (score 2):

[Asp.Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet) is what you are looking for. See [Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) overview for details

Comment: Yes but asp.net is a technology, it is not a MVC framework... Asp.net is the equivalent of jsp pages in Java...

Comment: @Miky-Bet nope, not familiar with JSP but it sounds like Razor pages is the equivalent. ASP.NET also supports MVC too. - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/mvc

Comment: @Miky-Bet Asp.Net is framework. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) overview of Asp.Net Core MVC

Comment: @Alexander Zhyshkevich thank you, I read a lot about but I can't understand why the call .net a framework... It make no sense

Comment: @Miky-Bet why? What is your definition of a "technology" or a "framework"? You don't need ASP.NET to create a web app or web api, you could build your own on top of sockets or slightly better, HttpListener. ASP.NET is more of a marketing name covering a family of frameworks created by Microsoft: WebForms, the original MVC and now in ASP.NET Core, with a complete cross-platform rewrite, ASP.NET Core MVC, Razor Pages, Web Api, gRPC.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos really thank you, you really help me to understand... So ASP .NET is only a "program" written with .net framework and other http suff that with IIS provide a way to create Web App... But everything still run on the top of .net framework which is CLR and Class libraries...

Comment: No, it's the marketing name for a family of frameworks. No, it's not IIS specific or a single program, or the name of a program written with the old .NET Framework or the current .NET Core. .NET Core is a completely new cross-platform runtime so it doesn't run on top of .NET Framework, which was Windows-specific

Comment: Everything web-related that comes out of Microsoft is called ASP.NET something or other. That's extremely well known, quite similar to just saying "Java" or "Node". There have been *numerous* frameworks under that brand over the years, as architectures and frankly, fashions changed. WebForms was created back when people wanted to design sites the way they designed desktop forms. ASP.NET MVC came after Ruby made MVC popular. Then came Web API, when people were asking for headless APIs, et. Outside Microsoft, there are other web frameworks like [Carter](https://github.com/CarterCommunity/Carter)